# Как правильно написать: "денежным вопросом" или "денежными вопросами"?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

> Здравствуйте, Любовь! Меня зовут Михаил, я занимаюсь денежными вопросами Фарида. До сегодняшнего дня с вами связалась девушка по имени Марьям, она теперь находится за рубежом и попросила меня заниматься этим делом...

Comment: Aqdam, если вы собирались отправлять текст в исходном виде кому-то, то в первую очередь стоило позаботиться хоть о каких-то знаках препинания, убрать заглавные буквы в середине предложения и т. д., а потом уже заботиться о числе "денежного вопроса". ;)

Answer (score 2):

Множественное число (денежными вопросами) указывает на то, что вы взяли на себя **ведение дел** человека, связанных с его финансами (всех или некоторых). Единственное число (денежным вопросом) указывало бы на какое-то **конкретное дело**, о котором известно и адресату: проблема какого-то долга, платежа и т. п. В зависимости от ситуации и выбирайте.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, у вас правильно стоит множественное число. Мне кажется, о ***денежном вопросе*** (в единственном числе) речь заходит, когда обсуждают эту тему как таковую.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так и эдак. Вы сами-то как считаете, вопрос один или несколько?

Но тут другое.

*Здравствуйте, Любовь! Меня зовут Михаил, я занимаюсь денежными вопросами Фарида. До сегодняшнего дня с вами **связывалась** девушка по имени Марьям, она теперь находится за рубежом и попросила меня **заняться** этим делом...*

Aqdam, вы совсем не чувствуете категории вида в русских глаголах.
Остальное уже исправили. Я бы еще и "сегодняшний день" заменил на "нынешний", но это уже устоялось, не смею настаивать.